# Check if value is within array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements with an attribute as the following

```
<li grouping-id="6080" class="show-item"></li>
<li grouping-id="9938" class="show-item"></li>
<li grouping-id="9633" class="show-item"></li>
```

I need to check whether each grouping-id is within the array or not.
If is NOT in the array, then remove the class "show-item"

This is what I am trying

```
var hiddenSoc = [6080,9633];

$("#filter .list li").each(function () {

   if($(this).is( "[grouping-id="+ hiddenSoc +"]" )) {
          $(this).removeClass("show-item");
    }

});
```

But at the moment, "hiddenSoc" is taking all of the arrays at a time.
I need to check each one of them at a time and remove the class if it's not within the array

Comment: You can't give an array as an argument equality.  You have to grab the grouping-id and see if it is in the array

Comment: Yes, but the code shown tries to do the opposite, hence the confusion, my apologies. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're concatenating an entire array in to the attribute selector. You instead need to find values in the array which match the current `grouping-id` and then add/remove the class as necessary.

To do that you can use a combination of `indexOf()` and `toggleClass()`, like this:

```js
var hiddenSoc = [6080, 9633];

$("#filter .list li").each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.toggleClass('show-item', hiddenSoc.indexOf($el.data('grouping-id')) != -1);
});
```

```css
.show-item {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter">
  <ul class="list">
    <li data-grouping-id="6080" class="show-item">A</li>
    <li data-grouping-id="9938" class="show-item">B</li>
    <li data-grouping-id="9633" class="show-item">C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that the `grouping-id` attribute is non-standard. As such I converted it to a `data-*` attribute, which can be used to store any custom metadata within an element. Also note the logic can be made even simpler if the `show-item` class is not present in the DOM at all when the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) and [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var hiddenSoc = [6080, 9633];

$("#filter .list li").filter(function() {
  return hiddenSoc.indexOf(+$(this).attr("grouping-id")) > -1;
}).removeClass("show-item");
```

```css
.show-item {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filter">
  <ul class="list">
    <li grouping-id="6080" class="show-item">1</li>
    <li grouping-id="9938" class="show-item">2</li>
    <li grouping-id="9633" class="show-item">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Or more condensed syntax : `$("#filter .list li").filter(() =>  !hiddenSoc.contains(+$(this).attr("grouping-id"))).removeClass("show-item")`

Comment: ah, indeed, my bad. What about `$("#filter .list li").filter( elem => !hiddenSoc.contains(+$(elem).attr("grouping-id"))).removeClass("show-item")`

Comment: @JeremyThille Sometimes, oldschool is the best. let it be. Is `contains()` belongs to `Array.prototype`?

Comment: Ah, I always mix up `contains` and `includes`. Yeah, sorry, just ignore my comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as another options, you could also use `not()` to perform the filtering.

```js
var hiddenSoc = [ 6080, 9633 ];
var exclusions = hiddenSoc.map( it => `[grouping-id="${it}"]` ).join( ',' );

$( '#filter .list li' ).not( exclusions ).removeClass( 'show-item' );
```

```css
#filter .list li:not(.show-item) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter">
  <ul class="list">
    <li grouping-id="6080" class="show-item">6080</li>
    <li grouping-id="9938" class="show-item">9938</li>
    <li grouping-id="9633" class="show-item">9633</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Selector by using `reduce` and provide it with a prefix of JQuery's `:not`. This will select anything that doesn't match the specified query.

```js
var hiddenSoc = [6080,9633],
socSelector = () => hiddenSoc.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc += `${i > 0 ? ",":""}[grouping-id="${v}"]`,"");


$(`li:not('${socSelector()}')`).each((i,e) => e.classList.remove("show-item"));
```

```css
.show-item {
  display: list-item;
}
li {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li grouping-id="6080" class="show-item">stuff</li>
<li grouping-id="9938" class="show-item">stuff</li>
<li grouping-id="9633" class="show-item">stuff</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the attribute value if not includes in the array:

```js
var hiddenSoc = [6080,9633];

$('#filter .list li').each(function(){
  var gid = Number($(this).attr('grouping-id'));
  if(!hiddenSoc.includes(gid))
    $(this).removeClass("show-item");
});
```

```css
.show-item{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter">
  <ul class="list">
    <li grouping-id="6080" class="show-item">111</li>
    <li grouping-id="9938" class="show-item">222</li>
    <li grouping-id="9633" class="show-item">333</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That was also my first answer, but someone pointed out it does exactly the opposite. OP wants to remove the class of elements that are NOT in the array.

Comment: @JeremyThille, I can't believe how I missed  *If is NOT in the array, then remove the class "show-item"*.....thanks for correcting me:)

Answer (score 0):

For my part i would have made it his way :

```
var hiddenSoc = [6080,9633];

$("#filter .list li").each(function () {
   if(!hiddenSoc.includes(parseInt($(this).attr("grouping-id"))))
   {
      $(this).removeClass("show-item");
   }
});
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) is the documentation for includes array function in JavaScript.

Instead of looking if your element attribut value IS one of the array value, think it the other way. Does my array contains my element attribut value. Check if a value is within an array vs Check if an array contain a specifique value.

Comment: This would need to use **`parseInt()`** because `.includes` is based on `===` comparisons, and you are now checking if strings are present in an array of numbers. Besides that, please don't put additions to your answer as comments, better to [edit] the answer instead.

Comment: @PeterB, yes that true, i missed this part.
`if(hiddenSoc.includes(parseInt($(this).attr("grouping-id"))))`
Thank you for your advise.

Comment: This does exactly the opposite of what OP wants. The goal is to remove the class of elements that are NOT in the array. Change your code to `!hiddenSoc.includes.....` and it should work